# Is there a way to put shadow just behind QSplashScreen?

Tags: python, pyqt, shadow, qsplashscreen

I'm trying to make a project, and I wanted to put shadow behind my QSplashScreen. Is there a way to do it ?

I searched, and the QGraphicsDropShadowEffect didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shadow effects are normally a responsibility of the OS.

For systems where those effects are not available you can create a "virtual" rasterized shadow, but there are some drawbacks:

- if the system *does* support shadow effects, the result will be ugly, as the system shadow will be drawn along with the custom one;
- the shadow effect is applied upon the appearance of the whole "root" window, so if some of the contents change while the splash is shown, those changes will not be reflected in the shadow effect;
- if the system does not support opaque move events (meaning that `moveEvent()` is only sent when a movement is *completed*), the shadow effect will show some artifacts;

This is a possible reimplementation of QSplashScreen that shows a shadow effect. The trick is to create a temporary QGraphicsScene and add a QGraphicsRectItem that has a QGraphicsDropShadowEffect applied on it.

```
class SplashTest(QtWidgets.QSplashScreen):
    _shadowSize = 8
    shadowCache = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.SplashScreen)
        self.desktopPixmap = QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen().grabWindow(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int)
    def shadowSize(self):
        return self._shadowSize

    @shadowSize.setter
    def shadowSize(self, shadowSize):
        if shadowSize == self._shadowSize:
            return
        self._shadowSize = shadowSize
        if self.shadowCache is None:
            self.shadowCache = {}
        else:
            self.shadowCache.clear()
        self.repaint()

    def setShadowSize(self, shadowSize):
        self.shadowSize = shadowSize

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        self.shadowCache.clear()
        super().setPixmap(pixmap)
        size = QtCore.QSize(pixmap.width() + self.shadowSize, pixmap.height() + self.shadowSize)
        self.setFixedSize(size)
        if self.isVisible():
            self.repaint()

    def drawShadow(self, event):
        if not self.pixmap() or self.pixmap().isNull():
            return
        shadowCache = self.shadowCache.get((self.width(), self.height()))
        if not shadowCache:
            # create the shadow effect if it's not cached yet
            self.shadowCache[(self.width(), self.height())] = shadowCache = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
            shadowCache.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

            # create a virtual QGraphicsScene to paint onto
            scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
            scene.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.desktopPixmap.rect()))
            # add a QGraphicsRectItem to the scene that will be used for the shadow
            pmItem = scene.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(self.pixmap().rect()).translated(self.geometry().topLeft()))
            pmItem.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
            pmItem.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.white))
            offset = QtCore.QPoint(self.shadowSize / 2, self.shadowSize / 2)
            effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(blurRadius=self.shadowSize, offset=offset)
            pmItem.setGraphicsEffect(effect)

            pmPainter = QtGui.QPainter(shadowCache)
            pmPainter.setRenderHints(pmPainter.Antialiasing)
            scene.render(pmPainter, QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()), pmItem.sceneBoundingRect().adjusted(0, 0, self.shadowSize, self.shadowSize))
            pmPainter.end()

        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        # draw the background taken from the root window
        qp.drawPixmap(event.rect(), self.desktopPixmap, event.rect().translated(self.pos()))
        # draw the shadow
        qp.drawPixmap(0, 0, shadowCache)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Paint:
            # intercept the Paint event in order to draw the shadow
            self.drawShadow(event)
        return super().event(event)

    def moveEvent(self, event):
        self.repaint()


def updateSplash():
    # remember: globals should *ALWAYS* be avoided unless you *really* know how to
    # use them; this is just for the purpose of this example
    global loadingStatus
    loadingStatus += 1
    splashTest.showMessage('Loading: {}%'.format(loadingStatus))
    if loadingStatus >= 100:
        timer.stop()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: splashTest.showMessage('Completed'))
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, splashTest.close)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    splashTest = SplashTest(shadowSize=16)
    splashTest.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('splash.png'))
    loadingStatus = 0
    timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=50, timeout=updateSplash)
    timer.start()
    splashTest.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What a great job !!! Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for ^^